# How to Improve Suspension on my bike Honda Shine

Tags: honda, motorcycle, suspension, shine-mc

My Bike has rear Suspension 3 Step Spring Loaded Hydraulic Shock Absorber & Bike total Weight (kgs) is 122 and its around 3yrs over 90000km run. i didn't feel comfort with suspension as now a days as it brings Back pain. I given my bike to friends - they also felt same problem. I checked with Honda Service center, they said suspension & Shock absorber is ok, i can change after 10000Km. But it doesnt solve my purpose and it getting worst now a days. kindly suggest.

is it possible to fit some other Bikes Damper(complete set) like Pulsar 150cc (weight 144kg),...

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading the suspension to that of a heavier bike may not be such a good idea. The rear suspension of the bike would become stiffer and that will not solve your back-ache. A faulty suspension will cause back ache, yes. But in your case you confirmed it with the service center. The reasons for you back pain could be mainly because of the riding position on your bike. Try another bike such as a pulsar 150/180 and see if that gives you any pain. Karizma R offers a very upright sitting position which could be very comfortable for you. My suggestion would then again be that upgrading to stiffer will not solve back aches. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think karizma or pulsar is more comfortable that the Honda Shine and i agree with "You shall not pass" do not install heavier suspension on your bike. take it to a different mechanic and double check if suspension is still broken